# Ubuntu firmware bug on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, firmware

## Error Log

```
[    0.079511] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x000000007a000000-0x000000007c7fffff], contact BIOS vendor for fixes
[    0.107935] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
```

## System info

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:130 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:df200000-df23ffff memory:df240000-df25ffff
```

Comment: Start by updating the firmware (UEFI).

Comment: @ChanganAuto How do I update the firmware?

Comment: UEFI is what replaced BIOS a decade ago. Likewise you go to the manufacturer's website to look for an update and instructions. This process is - should be - OS independent.

Comment: @ChanganAuto they are up-to-date

Comment: @ChanganAuto *already

Comment: does your system boot normally and otherwise work as you would expect? If it does, you can ignore "warnings" and "firmware bugs" errors that come up on boot. They are perfectly normal and don't affect anything unless you're doing kernel or driver development or something like that.